# Use case of binary data type in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to store binary data to Elasticsearch. Couple questions please:

1. The binary column very big(50MB), is that ok to store in ES.
2. I also need to get the binary data from ES, how harm it will impact
   the performance.
3. Can I query the binary column by some `binary patten` such as
   `0000111` or Base64 format.
4. What's the real use cases that people would like to use ES to store
   binary data.

Comment: What kind of binary data is that? Pictures, MS office(-ish) files or otherwise?

Comment: some binary executable files, such as:exe,apk, classes and gcc compile files :)